# Can you recommend good books for modular design?

Tags: architecture, module, refactoring, modularity

I am more interested in java related books, but don't have a problem to read in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it's easier to develop in an architecture which already has a good module structure than in a monolithic blob where you don't know what should go where and it's getting messier and messier.

Also, small modules can be tested more easily.

Additionally, you may detect mistakes early when defining the interfaces of the modules.